# Pandas Convert Week Date to Weekend Friday Date

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have a pandas data frame with a column that has dates like so:

```
DATE
01/16/2017
01/17/2017
01/18/2017
01/19/2017
01/20/2017
```

I need to convert each of those dates to a weekend date that is the date of the Friday of that corresponding week. So add a new column resulting in a data frame that looks like this:

```
DATE       WEEK_ENDING
01/16/2017  01/20/2017
01/17/2017  01/20/2017
01/18/2017  01/20/2017
01/19/2017  01/20/2017
01/20/2017  01/20/2017
```

Essentially I am looking for a Pandas solution to this question
[for a date get the friday of the week ending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41068602/for-a-date-get-the-friday-of-the-week-ending)

The format of the date itself is not that important. Is there a built in function that can do this or will I have to write one? Thanks!

Comment: Add 7 to each day and get the first Friday: `f = lambda x: pd.date_range(x, periods = 7)[pd.date_range(x, periods=7).weekday_name == 'Friday'][0]; df.DATE.apply(f)`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the built in [DateOffsets](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#parametric-offsets) to achieve this:

```
In [310]:
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
df['WEEK ENDING'] = df['DATE'] + Week(weekday=4)
df

Out[310]:
        DATE WEEK ENDING
0 2017-01-16  2017-01-20
1 2017-01-17  2017-01-20
2 2017-01-18  2017-01-20
3 2017-01-19  2017-01-20
4 2017-01-20  2017-01-27
```

Note that technically because the last day rolls onto the following week, also your date strings need to be converted to datetime first using `pd.to_datetime`:

```
df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'])
```

You can fix the last row by testing if the calculated offset is the same as the original data by subtracting a week and using `where`:

```
In [316]:
from pandas.tseries.offsets import *
df['WEEK ENDING'] = df['DATE'].where( df['DATE'] == (( df['DATE'] + Week(weekday=4) ) - Week()), df['DATE'] + Week(weekday=4))
df

Out[316]:
        DATE WEEK ENDING
0 2017-01-16  2017-01-20
1 2017-01-17  2017-01-20
2 2017-01-18  2017-01-20
3 2017-01-19  2017-01-20
4 2017-01-20  2017-01-20
```

Here it leaves the last row untouched

Comment: Posted the generic solution to this.

Comment: Instead of the whole "go to next friday unless next friday is exactly one week further than today)"... you could just `df['DATE'] + Week(weekday=4, n=0)` (where `n` is the number of weeks we want to advance)

Answer (score 2):

There is a fairly standard mathematical algorithm  you can use.

1)  Subtract the weekday (0-7) of the day you want the week to end on from the weekday of the dates you want adjusting.  In this case (and for Python), Friday=4, so you will be subtracting 4 from the weekday values of your individual dates.

2)  Take the result from step 1) and apply the modulus 7 if you want the value to go back to preceding Friday, or modulus -7 if you want it to go up to the next Friday.

3)  Use pd.to_timedelta on the result from 2) and subtract from your date.

This becomes a fairly simple formula (assuming you imported pandas as pd):

```
    df['week_ending'] = df['date'] - pd.to_timedelta((df['date'].dt.weekday-4)%-7,unit='d')
```

If you want to see the math in action, just run the `pd.to_timedelta((df['date'].dt.weekday-4)%-7,unit='d')` code on its own.  If I haven't made any typos, you should see Fridays=0 days, Saturdays=-6 days, Sundays=-5 days, etc. You can play around with moving the dates back to the previous Friday by doing `%7` instead of `%-7`.  Fridays still equal 0 days, Saturdays=1 days, Sundays=2 days, etc.  Neat trick, eh?

This is great to keep in your back pocket because it's generally applicable anywhere with some minor tweaks for however the software numbers its weekdays.